# How do i read the numbers of lines on a encrypted text file?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, windows-forms-designer

So i have this encrypt text files program (which works as desired), the problem is that i need to display this result on a MessageBox:

The numbers of lines readed BEFORE encrypting and AFTER the files is encrypted....

***the line-counter for the lines readed before encrypting already works WITH the same algorithm***

Ej. 'X' numbers of lines readed 'Y' numbers of line are encrypted.

i have this simple algorithm to read the encrypted file:

```
    public long CountlLines(string a)
    {
        long count = 0;
        string line;

        FileStream FS = new FileStream(a, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(FS);

        while (Reader.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            line = Reader.ReadLine();
            count++;
        }


        Reader.Close();
        return count;
    }
```

i got this 159 lines files that, when decrypted, produces 11 lines of encrypted code (opened on notepad), but with this algorithm i got:

Ej. '159' numbers of lines readed '1' numbers of line are encrypted.

The encryption method is AES, with a 128-bits key...(in case of...). Am i doing something wrong? or is there some kind of specific method or 'way' to read encrypted text? Thanks.

Comment: you meant to say that lines count after encrypting the content gives wrong?

Comment: Notepad is auto breaking lines, better use Notepad++

Comment: You can't read the number of lines in an encrypted file before decrypting it - not in any meaningful sense, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your encrypted file contains no newline markers. Thus when your "Reader.ReadLine()" executes, it does what you asked it to. It reads the lines until it comes to a newline, which there arent any of, because you have encrypted them all. Its all one line now.

Assuming of course you have encrypted the entire contents, and not line by line ;)

Comment: thank you very much, I had the same theory when i start to look for other 'methods' to read lines, but i didn't have the source to confirm it. :)

Comment: The ciphertext might contain newline characters (1/256 chance that any given byte is '\n'), but they are not meaningful in any way, since the ciphertext is binary data and not text.